# How to solve this set of coupled ODEs?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the system of coupled ODEs?

$$\cases{x^2\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2}=f(f^2-1)+g^2f\\\\x^2 \frac{d^2g}{dx^2}=2gf^2}$$ where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are smooth functions.

I saw that the solutions are given in the form $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sinh(x)}$ and $g(x)=\frac{x}{\tanh(x)}-1$. However, I cannot find a way to approach the equations.

Could anyone please help me?